# Proving a statement about self-complementary cycle graphs

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I'm a little confused on how to provide a proof of the following question:
"Let A be a (undirected) graph with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ vertices such that A is a cycle. Prove that

A is a self-complementary graph if and only if $n=5$

How do you prove this?

Answer (score 3):

For a cycle graph to be self-complementary, the complement graph must have the same number of edges as its original.

This can only happen when $n=5$, as the number of edges in $G+G'=\frac {n(n-1)}{2}$, so we require $n(n-1)=4n$, or $n^2-5n=0$ which only has solutions $n=0,5$.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a sketch of the proof; I encourage you to fill out the details.

Remember the definition of self-complementarity: A graph $G = (V,E)$ is self-complementary if there exists an isomorphism between it and the complementary graph $\overline{G} = (V, \binom{V}{2} \setminus E)$, where $\binom{V}{2}$ denotes the set of *unordered pairs* of vertices.

The statement to be proved is a bi-implicative statement. If $n=5$, then the complement of the 5-cycle $A$ is the "pentagram" graph; it is easy to see that this graph is isomorphic to the cycle. I will leave it to you to fill out the details of this.

For the reverse implication, it is easier to use a contrapositive proof.

We also make use of the fact that if a graph $G_1$ is isomorphic to a cycle graph $G$, that $G_1$ will have precisely one cycle.

So suppose $n \neq 5$. The cases $n=3$ and $n=4$ are simple, as the complement graphs here have no cycles. For $n >5$, find out how many cycles the complement graph will have.

Comment: Another simple way to show that the $n = 5$ case is the only self-complementary one is to inspect the degrees.

Comment: Also note that as the edges are unordered, in the definition of the complement you should have (depending on notational preferences) $\binom{V}{2} \setminus E$ or $V^{(2)} \setminus E$, not $V \times V \setminus E$.

Answer (score 1):

let A' be the complement graph of A with n vertices,$$$$ since we know that A is self-complementary which implies that A and A' are isomorphic.more specifically,the degree of vertices of A and A' must be equal (in some order)$$$$
now, if we choose some arbitary vertex v1 of A with degree d1 in A then degree of v1 in A' =n-1-d1 which should be equal to degree of some other vertex in A (since A and A' are isomorphic) let say that vertex is v2 with degree d2 in A$$$$
So we have d2 = n-1-d1 or, d1+d2=n-1 so, d1 and d2 form a "pair of vertices" such that sum of degrees is n-1.$$$$
by the same argument we can say  that all the vertices will form such "pairs" whose sum of degrees is n-1. So, the degrees of vertices of A will be like B1 , n-1-B1 , B2 , n-1-B2......Bk , n-1-Bk (where Bi's are arbitrary numbers chosen properly such that both Bi , n-1-Bi >=0)$$$$
Note that in the case when n is odd there will be one vertex remaining which will not be paired this vertex will have degree (n-1)/2 (it follows from the argument given above)$$$$
Finally, as we know that A is cycle graph (which is a 2-regular graph) so, we can say that B1 = B2 = B3=.......Bk = n-1-B1 = n-1-B2 =.......n-1-Bk = 2$$$$
which implies n-2-1 = 2 $$$$ so, n = 5$$$$
proving the converse is very trivial since  If n=5, then the complement of the 5-cycle A is the "pentagram" graph; it is easy to see that this graph is isomorphic to the cycle.